# Has Amazon Music "sample this album" been deliberately degraded by Amazon?

Tags: amazon-music

The sampler for the following album is heavily glitched, including multiple glitches in the first track.

[https://www.amazon.com/Gleam-Etherine/dp/B000TPTM46](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000TPTM46)

I've heard the real album before, and it does not sound like this.  So it's safe to assume something went wrong with this, right?  It is not a deliberate feature that Amazon Music applies to the sampler?

I've only used Amazon Music once, a few years ago.

I tested on both Firefox 61.0.1 and Google Chrome 67.0.3396.99 on Fedora Linux 28.

Comment: Sounds like a one-off problem to me. I've not encountered bad samples on other Amazon Music offerings.

Comment: wouldn't say "deliberately", but yeah, something went wrong during ripping of those tracks. contacting their support should resolve it.

Comment: http://moodmixes.com/i/Electronica/etherine-gleam